# stdout from child_process spawn, writes output twice from python program called in NodeJS

Tags: python, node.js, request, stdout, child-process

I'm running python from NodeJS. the stout part of below code runs my python program twice. any idea why?

```
NodeJS----------------------------------------------
server.js file********************
app.get('/xyz', pythonRoute.xyz);

xyz.js file***********************
const xyz = (req, res) => {
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const process = spawn('python',["./python/xyz.py"]);  
process.stdout.on('data', data => {
    console.log(data.toString());
})
};
exports.quandl = xyz;

frontend----------------------------------
 <form
    action={BackEnd_ServerName + "/xyz"}
    method="GET"
    onSubmit={submitSearch}
  >
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder=""
      name="frontEnd_searchBox"
    />
```

Comment: If `submitSearch()` doesn't prevent the default form submit, then your form gets submitted twice, once via Javascript and once by the browser causing your server route to get hit twice.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. even if I remove the onSubmit it will run twice. and if I add event.preventDefault() it won't even submit once.                                            <form action={BackEnd_ServerName + "/xyz"} method="GET" type="submit">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder=""
          name="frontEnd_searchBox"
        />

Comment: Well, you need to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) such that we could run it ourselves and debug the problem because the information you've shown so far is not making it clear what the problem is or why it is.